# Aggregating from multiple columns in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I have a table that looks like:

```
id     aff1    aff2    aff3    value
1       a        x      b        5
2       b        c      x        4
3       a        b      g        1
```

I would like to aggregate the aff columns to calculate the sum  of "value" for each aff. For example, the above gives:

```
aff    sum
a       6
b       10
c       4
g       1
x       9
```

Ideally, I'd like to do this directly in tableau without remaking the table by unfolding it along all the aff columns.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Tableau’s inbuilt pivot method as below, without reshaping in source .

1. CTRL Select all 3 dimensions you want to merge , and click on pivot .

[image]

2. You will get your new reshaped data as below, delete other columns :

[image]

3. Finally build your view.

[image]

I hope this answers . Rest other options for the above results include JOIN at DB level, or creating multiple calculated fields for each attribute value which are not scalable.

Comment: Doesn't Tableau only allow pivoting on Excel data sources...? (At least as of Desktop 10.4.) Any solution for all data sources, such as query results?

Comment: As of version 2018.1 unpivot can still be done only with excel and csv data sources. If you do not want to get out of Tableau to achieve this, you may use a **Custom SQL** using SQL keyword UNPIVOT in it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot?view=sql-server-2017