# Merge multiple dimensions together into one ( not the

Tags: tableau-api

The data I am using has 11 dimensions (service 1, service 2, etc...) that contain the same possible values (service_type a, service_type b, etc...). Essentially the same dimensions but just split out 11 times. What I am having trouble with is combing all the service_types together under one service dimension and getting a count for which are most utilized.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34427353/aggregating-from-multiple-columns-in-tableau

Comment: Thank you so much. This was exactly what I was looking for.